# 'Passenger 'command does not show running instance

Tags: config, passenger, phusion

I'm running my webserver using [Passenger Standalone](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html). I've been restarting the app as required after changes using `passenger-config restart-app`, which seems to work fine. If I run `passenger-status`, I see:

```
version : 5.0.30
Date    : 2017-02-13 20:15:49 -0800
Instance: ppGvpt93 (nginx/1.10.1 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.30)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
App groups    : 1
Processes     : 1
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/ubuntu/folder1/AppRoot/public (production):
  App root: /home/ubuntu/folder1/AppRoot
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 29006   Sessions: 0       Processed: 0       Uptime: 1m 46s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 18M     Last used: 1m 46s ago
```

Similarly, when I run `passenger-config list-instances`, I see:

```
Name                       PID      Description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ppGvpt93                   1396     nginx/1.10.1 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.30
```

However, within `/home/ubuntu/folder1/AppRoot`, when I run `passenger status`, I see:

```
Phusion Passenger Standalone is not running, according to PID file /home/ubuntu/folder1/AppRoot/tmp/pids/passenger.80.pid
```

What exactly is the difference between `passenger-config` and `passenger`, and why can I not see the running instance using the `passenger status` command? The reason this came up is I wanted to activate some Passenger configuration changes (specifically, add an environment variable to `Passengerfile.json`), but according to the [documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/standalone/restart_app.html):

> Restarting an application does not activate any Passenger Standalone
>   configuration changes. You have to restart Passenger Standalone for
>   Passenger Standalone configuration changes to take effect.

As a result, whereas `passenger-config restart-app` is working for most things, it's not working for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was nothing more than a user permissions problem (i.e. I needed to run `which passenger` on `ubuntu`, and then run `/path/to/passenger` on `root`), because I suppose a non-root user cannot listen on low port numbers.